# A function to time any other arbitrary function and return its results

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I am trying to write a function that accepts any other arbitrary function as an input and times it, then returns the results of that function. I have been at it for a couple hours now and think I'm getting pretty close, but I still can't quite figure out how to get it to compile.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Some arbitrary function to pass to the timer
int DoSomething(int x, double y)
{
    // Does something with x and y
    return 0;
}

// Function used to time another function and return its result
template <typename T, typename Function, typename... Args>
T GetRuntime(const std::string& name, const Function& function, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << name << " started..." << std::endl;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    T result = function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << name << " complete - duration: " << duration.count() << " milliseconds." << std::endl;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // Doesn't compile
    int output = GetRuntime("DoSomething", DoSomething, 42, 42.42);
}
```

Am I approaching this the right way? If so, what do I need to change to make this work? If not, what is a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: You can do it slightly differently by creating a scoped timer, and add that at the top of the function you want to call. The constructor will start the timer, destructor will stop it and print the duration. The only code you'd need to write at the start of the function is `ScopedTimer timer()`  <- or whatever you decide to name your struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `T` is not deducable in your function.  The value you are assigning the return to does not participate in template parameter deduction.  To use it as is, you need to specify the return type by using

```
int output = GetRuntime<int>("DoSomething", DoSomething, 42, 42.42);
                        ^^^ specify T is an int
```

but we can make this better by using `auto` for the return type of the function.  Using that turns the function into

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
auto GetRuntime(const std::string& name, const Function& function, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << name << " started..." << std::endl;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto result = function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << name << " complete - duration: " << duration.count() << " milliseconds." << std::endl;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Won't work if `function` returns `void`. Move all the timer stuff into a helper class's constructor and destructor. Construct the helper class in `GetRuntime`, then `return function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` will also work if `function` returns `void`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good points.  I'll leave that to the OP to implement if that is what they want.

Comment: I think I can handle that. Overall this is a good answer. I gave it a try and it compiles now. Marking it as accepted. :)

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Sounds good, and thank you.  If need help making it more generic, just ask a followup question.

Comment: It seems like even after making the suggested change to use a helper class it still doesn't work with void functions. I made the change and tried to pass in a void function and got "fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler"... Thanks Microsoft for the totally useless error message!

Comment: gcc will handle that just fine. A `return` in a `void` context, like that, was added in a recent standard, I forget which one, and it's possible that an older Microsoft compiler simply doesn't digest that at all.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler cannot infer `T`. It's a template argument but there is nothing in your parameter to deduce it.

However, You can use `std::invoke_result` to get the return type of your function:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args, typename R = std::invoke_result_t<Function, Args...>>
auto GetRuntime(const std::string& name, const Function& function, Args&&... args) -> R {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why is `R` a template argument here instead of using `std::invoke_result_t` directly in the trailing return type?

Comment: @KonradRudolph simply because it seemed like OP wanted to use a name instead of `auto`. Also, SFINAE

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot that was only because I didn't know what I was doing hahaha

Answer (score 2):

NathanOliver already gave a correct answer. This is just an answer on how to make the function more generic. It works with `void` functions as well and doesn't do any logging. It returns a tuple containing the duration and the return value of the passed function. If the passed function returns `void`, it just returns the duration directly (no tuple.)

(This is all C++17.)

```
// Need these includes in addition to what you already include.
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Function, typename... Args>
auto GetRuntime(const Function& function, Args&&... args)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(function(args...)), void>) {
        function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
    } else {
        auto&& func_result{function(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
        return std::make_tuple(
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start),
                std::forward<decltype(function(args...))>(func_result));
    }
}
```

You can use that directly to get the duration:

```
auto duration = GetRunTime(void_func, arg1, arg2);
cout << "Took " << duration.count() << "ms.\n";
```

With non-void functions, you use structured bindings:

```
auto [duration, int_val] = GetRunTime(int_func, arg1, arg2);
cout << "Took " << duration.count() << "ms and returned " << int_val << '\n';
```

Your original logging functionality can be implemented as a wrapper around `GetRuntime()`. The return type of the logging function is going to be the same as that of the passed function:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
auto LogRuntime(const std::string& name, const Function& function, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << name << " starting..." << std::endl;
    auto result = GetRuntime(function, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << name << " complete - duration: ";
    constexpr auto is_void = std::is_same_v<decltype(function(args...)), void>;
    if constexpr (is_void) {
        std::cout << result.count();
    } else {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(result).count();
    }
    std::cout << " milliseconds.\n";
    if constexpr (!is_void) {
        return std::get<1>(result);
    }
}
```